# Calculate multiple columns of a Select Statement with only one user defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have built a stored procedure in SQL Server with two output parameters. The only inputparameter of the stored procedure is the ID of a table. What i want to do now is to build a Table (ID, SP_Result1, SP_Result2).

My initial approach was to create a Cursor over ID, iterate through this Cursor, calculate the stored Procedure for the current ID and insert (@ID, @SP_Result1, @SP_Result2) into the Table Row by Row. Since i was using a Cursor runtime wasn't good. So my idea is now to replace the stored Procedure with two user defined functions such that i can replace the Cursor by

```
Insert into Table
Select
ID
,udf1(ID)
,udf2(ID)
From ID_Table
```

However in this scenario udf1 and udf2 calculate almost exactly the same thing and I could probably cut runtime in half if I was able to run only one udf but with 2 results much like i did with my original stored procedure.

Sample: The ID is a char(10) and the stored procedure I currently have is able to - by using other tables and doing quite a bit of calculations - calculate 2 decimal output variables for this ID. The calculation of the first and second output variable only forkes at the very end of the stored procedure, 95% of the calculation of Output1 and Output2 are exactly the same. What i **am** doing is therefore something like:

```
create Table result
(ID char(10)
,SP_Result1 decimal(28,12)
,SP_Result2 decimal(28,12))

declare @IDIterator char(10)
declare @SPResult1 decimal(28,12)
declare @SPResult2 decimal(28,12)
declare @Cursor Cursor

Set @Cursor = Cursor for
Select ID
From ID_Table
Open @Cursor
Fetch Next From @Cursor into @IDIterator

While (@@Fetch_Status=0)

Exec dbo.StoredProcedure
@ID = @IDIterator
,@SPResult1 = @SPResult1 Output
,@SPResutl2 = @SPresult2 Output

Insert Into result
Select
@ID
,@SPResult1
,@SPResult2

Fetch next
From @Cursor into @TransIterator

END
Close @Cursor
Deallocate @Cursor
```

What i **could** be doing is to splitt my Stored procedure into two user-defined-functions - 1 for the first result, the second for the second result. This way i would avoid the cursor:

```
create Table result
(ID char(10)
,SP_Result1 decimal(28,12)
,SP_Result2 decimal(28,12))

Insert into result
Select 
ID
,udf1(ID)
,udf2(ID)
From ID_Table
```

What I **would like to be doing** is to use a udf with two output variables as 2 columns of the final select since udf1 and udf2 would do almost the same calculations for the same Input ID. A non-working example of the desired code would look something like:

```
Insert into result
select
ID
,udf1(ID).Output1
,udf1(ID).Output2
From ID_table
```

In which udf1 is only calculated once per row.

Is it somehow possible to do this? I've looked into Table-Valued functions but I couldn't figure out how those could help me with this problem.

Comment: Can you please add some sample input and expected output data? Your question is unclear as it stands.

Comment: Yes we can create a TVF as required. Please post your function definition..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create table value function like -

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].udf(@ID  INT)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
    SELECT 1 AS Output1, 2 AS Output2

GO
```

And then can call function or join with table using cross apply

```
SELECT
I.ID,RESULT.OUTPUT1,RESULT.OUTPUT2
FROM ID_TABLE I
CROSS APPLY DBO.UDF(I.ID) RESULT
```